# How to set json object from json array in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, ajax, json

Here I am getting JSON object in the following format.

```
{"userid":"12345","cmpyname":"stackoverflow",
"starrays":[{"transaction":"7272785","value2":"ABCDE"},    
{"transaction":"4774585","value2":"CDEFG"}],"value3":"95345"}
```

Explanation:

For Particular userid (12345), it will return some set of arrays - starrays with same object names like `transaction`, `value2`

Here, I am setting userid and cmpyname like below.

```
<div id="t_userid"></div>
<div id="t_cmpy"></div>
```

In ajax, I am getting JSON object and setting the values to the div elements like below.

```
$('#userid').html(data.userid);

$('#t_cmpy').html(data.cmpyname);
```

Now, I need to know how can I get the values of transaction and value2 objects from the array?.

```
<div id="t_trans"></div>
<div id="t_val2"></div>
```

I tried like this. But didn't work.

```
$('#t_trans').html(data.starrays.transaction);

$('#t_val2').html(data.starrays.value2);
```

And, here mutiple values are there in the array, how can I set to my div one by one. (not appending values)

Edit:

```
{"userid":"12345","cmpyname":"stackoverflow",
"starrays":[{"transaction":"7272785","addr":"ABCDE"},    
{"transaction":"4774585","addr":"ABCDE"}],"value3":"95345"}
```

Here, I am having same value in addr object as ABCDE.

In this case, if I use like below it is working

```
$('#divid1').html(data.starrays[1].addr);
```

But, I am having different value in transaction as 7272785, 4774585.

In this case, if I use like below it is not working

```
$('#divid2').html(data.starrays[0].transaction);
```

Answer (score 1):

The array in your code doesn't have a closing bracket. I assume you just pasted a portion though..

You need to reference the array index:

```
$('#t_trans').html(data.starrays[0].transaction);
```

Comment: Edited closing bracket..Will check this

Comment: Worked! And one more doubt...I am getting multiple values for the same div id. So How can I use it as separate one?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand bud. Can you clarify?

Comment: Actually, for transaction object, it is having same value for all the arrays. But, for value2 object, it is not showing the value because, it has ABCDE in first array and CDEFG in second array...

Comment: Not sure what you want to do.. Make a jsfiddle and I can help you out

Comment: And also after 3 values, I cant able to retrive the values from the array using index